# some type of pipe/conduit exposed after drilling through top plate in attic ...not sure what it is

Tags: hvac, gas, conduit

i'm a new home owner and was running wire through my attic for a recessed lighting install.  i drilled through the top plate and once i broke through i took out my borescope to inspect the surrounding area.  i noticed this line that was running across one of the studs and am not sure what it is, so stopped drilling out of, obvious, caution.

more info about home: this is a condo in northeast usa.  i have 10 ft ceilings in the upstairs, so after i got through the top plate there is this other layer which you see in the photo below.  beyond this wire/pipe is a layer of insulation which has another stud below it (which leads to the switch i need to get to).  the photos show the pipe/wire moving horizontally in the direction from the attic to the bedroom upstairs (interior wall).

[image][image]

Comment: Probably not good to drill into, but without more information about the house hard to tell.  First guess is electric conduit for wires, but gas  or water line is next guess.

Comment: Clue, since it is in the attic and it is bend it is probably not water or gas, it is probably a drain vent hose

Comment: My first thought is Romex, but some more description would be very helpful.  Which way is up?  Which piece of wood is a vertical stud, and what is the other piece of wood?  Is this an interior or exterior wall?

Comment: i've added some more details about the home in the question

Answer (score 1):

If that's the interior of a 4" wall, the object looks too thin to be a pipe or conduit. If the entire screen constitutes the 4" cavity (which is actually a little less than 4"), the object is very thin. To me it looks like a poorly-driven nail - one that missed it's mark.

Comment: i don't think it's a nail....there is a nut or some type of protective shielding on the side of the stud the mysterious item is coming from

Comment: It doesn't seem like a bushing to me - it's looks like the wood that splintered as the nail was driven through. Tough call.